# libvirt and dnsmasq does not allow to start Kea DHCP server

Tags: libvirt, dhcp-server, dnsmasq

I have `libvirt` installed which instantiates `dnsmasq` process per each virtual bridge interface, e.g. virbr0, however for some reason I can't start kea-dhcp server on other interfaces in the system, unless I kill `dnsmasq` process completely.

I'm wondering if there's a way to disable dnsmasq via libvirt configuration, but more interesting question is why another dhcp server can't start on interfaces, not occupied by dnsmasq?

Thanks.